# What exactly prevents this code from compiling?

Tags: compile

I am trying to compile a function that operates on an initial array (doing some sequential operation) to produce a matrix (which consists of N iterations of the initial array).

Below is a minimal working example:

```
NT = 10^1; NM = 2;
minitial = 2 RandomInteger[{}, NM] - 1.;
mzero = ConstantArray[0, {NT, NM}];

networkStep = 
  Compile[{{minitial, _Integer, 
     1}, {NT, _Integer}, {NM, _Integer}, {mzero, _Real, 2}}, 
   Block[{md = minitial, moo = mzero}, 
    Rescale@Table[
      Do[md[[j]] = Sign[RandomReal[{-1, 1}]], {j, Range@NM}]; 
      moo[[i, ;;]] = md, {i, 1, NT}]]];

mm = networkStep[minitial, NT, NM, mzero]
```

What prevents this function from compiling? Everything seems localized and appropriately defined to me.

Comment: `Rescale` isn't compilable: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/1871 `;;` (whose `FullForm` is `1;;All`) cannot be compiled, either: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61651/1871

Comment: Thank you - replacing ;; with All fixed the problem. Rescale seems like it can't be compiled but it does compile and speeds things up.

Comment: `Rescale` results in a `MainEvaluate` in the output of `CompilePrint`, but given it's called only once, it doesn't cause significant slowing down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on xzczd's comment, replacing ";;" with "All" in the code fixed the compilation problem (Rescale does not pose a problem):

```
NT = 10^5; NM = 2;
minitial = 2 RandomInteger[{}, NM] - 1.;
mzero = ConstantArray[0, {NT, NM}];

networkStep = 
  Compile[{{minitial, _Integer, 
     1}, {NT, _Integer}, {NM, _Integer}, {mzero, _Real, 2}}, 
   Block[{md = minitial, moo = mzero}, 
    Rescale@Table[
      Do[md[[j]] = Sign[RandomReal[{-1, 1}]], {j, Range@NM}];
      moo[[i, ;;]] = md, {i, 1, NT}]], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

mm = AbsoluteTiming[networkStep[minitial, NT, NM, mzero]]; mm[[1]]
```

gives

1.11684 seconds

while

```
NT = 10^5; NM = 2;
minitial = 2 RandomInteger[{}, NM] - 1.;
mzero = ConstantArray[0, {NT, NM}];

networkStep = 
  Compile[{{minitial, _Integer, 
     1}, {NT, _Integer}, {NM, _Integer}, {mzero, _Real, 2}}, 
   Block[{md = minitial, moo = mzero}, 
    Rescale@Table[
      Do[md[[j]] = Sign[RandomReal[{-1, 1}]], {j, Range@NM}];
      moo[[i, All]] = md, {i, 1, NT}]], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

mm = AbsoluteTiming[networkStep[minitial, NT, NM, mzero]]; mm[[1]]
```

gives 0.025396 seconds.